# jenkins java plugin field gives Bad Message 414 reason: URI Too Long

Tags: java, jenkins, plugins

When field in my plugin is filled with about 5000 characters it gives error:

```
Bad Message 414
reason: URI Too Long
```

When I make it less a bit, it gives:

```
Bad Message 431
reason: Request Header Fields Too Large
```

config.jelly:

```
<f:entry field="field" title="Example">
   <f:textarea value="${it.getField()}"/>
</f:entry>
```

java:

```
private String field;
...
public FormValidation doCheckField(@QueryParameter String value)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
    if (value.length() == 0) {
        return FormValidation.error("Please set an input");
    } else {
        return FormValidation.ok();
    }
}
```

Comment: IRC, IE also imposes a 2000 char limit

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/417142/what-is-the-maximum-length-of-a-url-in-different-browsers

Comment: @ScaryWombat The point is to fix this issue, like changing the method of sending this data. And I am using Chrome. I assume this error message is given by plugin not by a browser.

Comment: Why the downvote on this one, I'm experiencing the exact same issue?!?  Thank you for posting!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It was fixed by adding to Jenkins config

- `/etc/sysconfig/jenkins` for default SLES installation
- `C:\Program Files (x86)\Jenkins\jenkins.xml` in Windows

---

```
JENKINS_ARGS="--requestHeaderSize=32768"
```